# How to send email after registering

Tags: database, email, registration, activation

After that someone registers in a site, a mail is usually sent to his mail account. But to generate this link or what info can be placed in this link so that it can be used to activate the user account??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can place any thing which can identify a valid user

1- A Hash Value

2- An Encrypted String

3- A Guid

and when user clicks on the link , you can validate the value.

Answer (score 1):

Check this part of code:

Generate code and e-mail:

```
/* if $acces = 0 everything is perfect so the system send a confirmation mail */ 
                                if($acces == 0) 
{ 
    print("<br>A mail has been send to " . $mail . "<br><br>") ; 

    /* prepare the vars */ 
    $activ = $user . $pass ; 
    $code = md5($activ) ; 
    /* to how send to mail */ 
    $to = $mail ; 
    /* prepare the subject */ 
    $subject = "You need to confirm you registration to " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ; 
    /* start writing the message */ 
    $message = "Hello " . $user . ",\r\n\r\n" ; 
    $message .= "Thank you for registering at " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . " Your account is created and must be activated before you can use it.\r\n" ;
    $message .= "To activate the account click on the following link or copy-paste it in your browser :\r\n\r\n" ; 
    $message .= "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/~carron/registration/register_send.php?user=" . $user . "&activation=" . $code . "\r\n\r\n" ; 
    $message .= "After activation you may login to http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . " using the following username and password:\r\n\r\n" ; 
    $message .= "Username - " . $user . "\r\nPassword - " . $pass . "\r\n" ; 

    /* To send HTML mail, you can set the Content-type header. */ 
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"; 

    /* set up additional headers */ 
    $headers .= "To: " . $to . "<br>\n" ; 
    $headers .= "From: " . $from . $addmail ; 

    /* writing data in the base */ 
    $query = "INSERT INTO registration (user, pass, activ, mail) VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$code', '$mail') ;" ; 

    $result = mysql_query($query, $db); 

    if ($result == false) 
        die("Failed " . $query); 
    else 
        { 
            /* everything went well so we can mail it now */ 
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
        } 
}
```

Check activation:

```
/* controle if the validation link is right */ 
$x = 0 ; 

$query = "SELECT user, pass, activ, mail FROM registration WHERE user = '" . $username . "';" ; 

$result = mysql_query($query, $db); 

if ($result == false) die("Failed " . $query); 


while ($fields = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
        { 
         for ($i=0, $max=sizeof($fields) ; $i < $max ; $i++) 
                { 
                    $tmp[$i] = $fields[$i] ; 
                } 

         /* the activation link is right so we can update 
         the datas in the data base */ 
         if($activation == $tmp[2] AND $username == $tmp[0]) 
            { 
                $x = 1 ; 
                $query2 = "UPDATE registration SET activated = '1' WHERE user = '" . $username . "' AND activ = '" . $activation . "' ;" ; 

                $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $db); 

                if ($result2 == false) 
                    die("Failed " . $query2); 
            } 
         else 
            $x = -1 ; 
        } 

/* give a confirmation message to the user */ 
if($x == 1) 
    print($username . " your activation has been done perfectly<br> Thank you...") ; 
else 
    print($username . " your activation has not been done corectly<br> Please try again later...") ;
```

[Script from PHPclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2159-PHP-User-registration-with-CAPTCHA-image-validation.html)

Comment: You do realize that you're not properly quoting/escaping anything in your SQL, right?

Comment: Of course I am :) That is not actually my code. I found it today on PHPclasses.org

Answer (score 0):

When user registered, you can use `uniqid()` to create an activate code and stored in database. Then in mail, give a link like: `http://....../activate.php?code=[uniqid()]`
In `activate.php`, you can read activate code from database and check it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a link that only the recipient of the email knows. So when that link is visited on your site, you know that someone has read the email you sent and clicked on the link and so you can presume that the person who registered and the person who read the email are the same.

As such, you just need a link that can't be easily guessed. Pick something random (and record it in the user's profile) or hash the user name + a seed, or something.